# Rails 3 ThinkingSphinx multitenancy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

We're in the middle of a bit of a big upgrade:

- `Rails` 2.3 to `Rails` 3.2
- `ThinkingSphinx` 1.4.1 to `ThinkingSphinx` 3.0.6
- `Sphinx` 0.9.9 to `Sphinx` 2.0.8

And now our `ThinkingSphinx` configuration is broken. We have a multi-tenant setup, so it's a bit complicated as to how we connect. Our method `set_sphinx_connection` is called every time the search action is fired off. Here's how we used to do it:

```
def set_sphinx_connection
  Thread.current[:thinking_sphinx_environment] = "tenant_#{Tenant::active.id}"
  ThinkingSphinx::Configuration.instance.reset
end
```

And here's how we're trying to do it now:

```
def set_sphinx_connection
  framework = ThinkingSphinx::Frameworks::Plain.new
  framework.environment = "tenant_#{Tenant::active.id}"
  ThinkingSphinx::Configuration.instance.framework = framework
end
```

Each tenant has its own sphinx config file, and each is searching on its own port. An excerpt from our thinking_sphinx.yml is below:

```
tenant_1:
  mysql41: 9312
  enable_star: true
  min_infix_len: 1
tenant_2:
  mysql41: 9313
  enable_star: true
  min_infix_len: 1
tenant_3:
  mysql41: 9314
  enable_star: true
  min_infix_len: 1
```

If you only ever search on one tenant, it works just fine. However, when you search on one and then another, one of two errors are occurring:

- stale ID errors on the second tenant
- the search returns in counts from the first tenant to the second tenant

Does anyone have a way of getting this working? Pat if you're out there can you help?

UPDATE: We think it has to do with `Passenger`. When the first instance starts up, it works for that tenant consistently. However, from then on that passenger instance cannot search any other tenant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting this here in case someone else runs into this same issue. This was what ended up working.

```
def set_sphinx_connection
  framework = ThinkingSphinx::Frameworks::Plain.new
  framework.environment = "tenant_#{Tenant::active.id}"
  ThinkingSphinx::Configuration.instance.framework = framework
  ThinkingSphinx::Connection.pool.clear
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because Thinking Sphinx v3 persists Sphinx connections between searches. This can be disabled, but that feature appeared in TS v3.1.0, which will mean some more tweaks.

```
# in an initializer:
ThinkingSphinx::Connection.persistent = false
```

If you're sticking with Sphinx 2.0.8 (instead of, say, 2.1.4), please make sure you read the TS v3.1.0 release notes (which are probably worth a read anyway): https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/releases/tag/v3.1.0

Comment: Thanks @Pat! We ended up coming up with a slightly different solution - but I appreciate the answer because this pointed us to it. I've posted it below - could you check it out and tell us if it's crazy?